# Can you limit a blog archive to a specific category?

Tags: categories

I am not sure why this doesn't work:

```
<h3>Archives</h3>
    <ul>
            {exp:channel:month_links channel="blog" limit="12" category_id="41" show_empty="no"}
                    <li><a href="{path='fr/blog/archives'}">{month}, {year}</li>
            {/exp:channel:month_links}
    </ul>
```

I'm getting archives of months that have no entries from the category show up in the ul, so if you click them, you'd get a blank page.  Why aren't they being filtered out by the 'show_empty="no"' tag?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [list of parameters in the user guide](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/archive_month_links.html#parameters), the `month_links` tag doesn't support the `category` parameter. You could use [Low Yearly Archives](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives), which does allow you to filter the archive links by category.